# Java Test URL Request Test

Tags: java, html, eclipse, url, request

Hello I am a newbie to java and programming so forgive me if I am wrong with something easy. My goal is to import a text file, scan each line, test the line(Which is a URL) if something is read, then print it to an output file. So the program is testing the each URL and if URL is is valid(working) I will print the line in a new output file.

My problem is the test URL section. It reads the line so it will print the URL, but it prints multiple times any suggestions? Is there any way to make it print once? I think I understand that it prints multiple times because its reading the HTML code line by line.

```
try
{
    // Test URL Connection
    URL url = new URL("http://www." + line);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while((lines = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reading lines into a variable named "lines", but you are printing out the line variable. The line variable is what you used to create your URL:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www."+line);
```

If you only want to print out the url, then you might want to consider constructing the url as a string like this:

```
String targetUrl = String.format("http://www.%s", domainName);
System.out.println(targetUrl);
```

And then create the URL object.

```
URL url = new URL(targetUrl);
```

If you are trying to print out the content being retrieved from the target URL, then change the code to print out "lines" instead:

```
System.out.println(lines);
```

It would be even better to use more descriptive variable names.  For example, instead of constructing a URL using "line", use a variable name like "domainName".  Then, when you are reading a line at a time, you can use the variable name of "line".

```
// Assuming that domainName is set before the try block
try
{
    // Test URL Connection
    URL url = new URL("http://www."+domainName);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();

    String line = null;

    // Get the response
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(line);                       
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```